# Groups for which all projections of $C^*_{\text{red}}G$ belong to $\mathbb{C}G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, group-rings

**Revision:**  According to comment of Wojowu we give a complete revise for this post.

A group $G$ is a pr-group if all projections of $C^*_{\text{red}} G$ are contained in its dense subalgebra $\mathbb{C}G$.

What is a counterexample of this situation?
Is there a characterisation of pr-groups?

Comment: Can't you take for any $G$ the augmentation map $\mathbb C[G]\to\mathbb C$ and compose it with inclusion $\mathbb C\hookrightarrow\mathbb C[G]$?

Comment: @Wojowu yes my question is stupid for finite group since the group algebra is the reduced algebra. But this property can be defined for arbitrary group

Comment: I should say " Let G be a group with non trivial torsion"

Comment: @Wojowu or I could say "a pr-group is a group for which all projections of $C^*_{red} G$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}G$"

Comment: Which idempotents are counted as trivial?  Only $0$ and $1$, or others?

Comment: @LSpice yes these are counted as trivial. On the other hand for every torsion $g$ the element $1/n\sum_0^n \lambda^i g^i$ is a non trivial idempotent.

Comment: Where $g^n=1$ and $\lambda$ is the nth root of unity.

Comment: Could you edit your question?

Comment: @YCor Yes I completely changed it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Wojowu according to your comment I changed my question. Thanks for your atention.

Comment: @LSpice I modified the question. Please see this new version.

Answer (score 6):

If the group is torsion-free, pr-ness is clearly implied by the Kadison–Kaplansky conjecture, so providing a counterexample in the torsion-free case seems to be difficult.

However, every group containing the free product $\Gamma=\mathbb Z/n \ast \mathbb Z$ is non-pr. Indeed, let $g$ denote the generator of $\mathbb Z/n$ and $t$ the generator of $\mathbb Z$, and let $p = \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g^n$ be the projection coming from the torsion part.

The group C*-algebra $C^*_r(\mathbb Z)$ has lots of unitaries which have infinitely many nonzero Fourier coefficients: for instance, $u = \exp(i\cdot(t+t^{-1}))$ (it corresponds via Fourier transform to the function $\exp(2i\cdot\cos\theta)$ on the circle). Let's write its Fourier expansion as $u = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} u_kt^k$.

Now, $upu^*$ is clearly a projection in $C^*_r(\Gamma)$. Its Fourier coefficient at $t^k g t^{-\ell}$ is equal to $u_k\overline{u_\ell}/n$, so infinitely many Fourier coefficients are non-zero, and hence in can't belong to $\mathbb C\Gamma$.

I believe, one can relax the freeness condition to something significantly milder (intuitively, one requires an element $t$ of infinite order whose conjugation action on $g$ produces sufficiently many independent elements), but I haven't thought much further.